# Tkinter Button Commands in For Loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using python 3 with tkinter and I am having issues with a command I want to execute from a button.  A variable number of buttons are generated, one for each visitor, and I am trying to call the function `signOut` from the button press whilst passing the relevent item (visitor) from the list to it.

I realise that the issue is with the for loop as by the time the button is pressed, `i` will `==` the last item in the list.  How can I make it specific to the actual visitor.  I can't seem to think of the solution.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
buttonDictionary = {}
for i in range(0,len(currentVisitors)):
    buttonDictionary[i] = Button(bottomFrame, text=currentVisitors[i], command=lambda: signOut(topFrame, bottomFrame, currentVisitors[i]))
    buttonDictionary[i].pack()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that e.g. `i` in a `lambda` within a loop like this is referring to the variable `i` itself, not the value of the variable on each iteration, so that when the `command` callback is called, it will use the value of `i` at that moment, which as you noticed is the value on the last iteration.

One way to solve this is with a `partial`. `partial` will, in effect "freeze" the arguments at their current state in the loop and use those when calling the callback.

Try using a `partial` instead of a `lambda` like this:

```
from functools import partial

buttonDictionary = {}
for i in range(0,len(currentVisitors)):
    buttonDictionary[i] = Button(bottomFrame, text=currentVisitors[i], command=partial(signOut, topFrame, bottomFrame, currentVisitors[i]))
    buttonDictionary[i].pack()
```

Another way I have seen this done, but haven't tried, is to assign `i` to a new variable in your `lambda` each time:

```
command=lambda i=i: signOut(topFrame, bottomFrame, currentVisitors[i])
```

I have gotten burned bad more than once when I first started with Python by using lambdas in loops (including a case very similar to this trying to assign a callback to dynamically generated buttons in a loop). I even created a snippet that would expand to `think_about_it('are you sure you want to use a lambda?')` whenever I typed `lambda` just to remind me of the pain I caused myself with that...

Comment: That did indeed solve the problem.  Thanks a lot for your reply!

Comment: @user3931640 Glad it worked! I have been burned by this a few times. The worst thing is when you don't notice it is happening. I will try to update my answer a little bit with an explanation as to *why* this happens, or at least link to someone who can explain it well.