# python tkinter buttons how to call functions with command

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, button, tkinter

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self):
        ls = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "-", "+", "/", "x", "=", "a", ".")
        column = 5
        row = 5
        count = 2

        for x in ls:
            bt=Button(root, text=x, command="")


            for y in x:

                bt.grid(row=(row), column=(column))
                column = column + 1
                count = count + 1
                if count> row:
                    column = column-4
                    row = row +4


cal=Calc()
```

Above is my code. My question is how can I call a function so that the button pressed, for instance button 1, prints 1 into the console. Only seem to be able to print the whole list of 1, 16 buttons or I can print the very last position in the list which is ".". I can't print 1 or 2 or 3 etc?

Comment: this code is all in the class Calc by the way

Comment: I think your problem is similar as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174661/tkinter-button-commands-in-for-loop)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7032856.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` to assign function with parameter.

If you use `lambda` in `for` you have to use `char=item` in `lambda`

```
command=lambda char=item:self.on_press(char)
```

because when you use `lambda:self.on_press(item)` then it use reference to `item`, not value from `item`. And it will get value from `item` when you press button but after `for` loop you have last value from list and all button get the same value.

Full code

```
import tkinter as tk    

class Calc:

    def __init__(self, master):
        ls = (
            ("1", "2", "3"),
            ("4", "5", "6"),
            ("7", "8", "9"),
            ("-", "+", "/"),
            ("x", "=", "a"),
            (".")
        )

        for r, row in enumerate(ls):
            for c, item in enumerate(row):
                bt = tk.Button(master, text=item, command=lambda char=item:self.on_press(char))
                bt.grid(row=r, column=c)

    def on_press(self, char):
        print(char)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
cal = Calc(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you furas that solved it for me as im sure your aware. I actually did try using lambda but just wasn't sure the best way to implement it. Thanks again !